# PHP check if a value is equal to any value in another result set?

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a while loop which is printing out rows from search results, one column in the search result is 'Area Name'. 
Now I want to check if that area name is also in another result set, and if it is, make the product clickable.

This is my while loop for search results:

```
<table id="" class="table table-striped table-bordered display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Customer Code</th>
        <th>Customer Name</th>
        <th>Customer Type</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Postcode</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php while($customer = sqlsrv_fetch_array($querySearchResults, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $customer['CardCode'] ?></td>
            <td>
                //If $customer['Name'] = to any of the rows in other query 
                    //This is Clickable
                    <?php echo $customer['CardName']; ?>
                //Else its not.
            </td>
            <td><?php echo $customer['CardType'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $customer['Name'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $customer['ZipCode'] ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?> 
</tbody>
</table>
```

This is the other Query:

```
$userID = $user['loggedInUserId'];
$queryName = "
    SELECT UserID, Name
    FROM Table
    WHERE UserID = '$userID'";
$getName = sqlsrv_query($sapconn2, $queryName);
$Name = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getName, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
```

What would the if statement need to be in this case?

Comment: If the results are in an array you can check with `in_array()`.

Comment: Rather inconsistant code here. `The other Query` only seems to return one row OR you at least you are only retrieving one row! So if thats the case  all you need to do is `if ($customer['Name'] == $Name['name'] ){`

Comment: yes, I see what you mean, it's only ever going to return one row, isn't it. That's where I was going wrong, I may have to change my SQL to include another WHERE clause and check that way. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your sample code explains the real situation, your `other Query` only seems to retrieve one row. So in your main code, again assuming you have completed the `other Query` before that is run just needs to do

```
<?php while($customer = sqlsrv_fetch_array($querySearchResults, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $customer['CardCode'] ?></td>
        <td>
<?php
if ($customer['Name'] == $Name['name']) {
    //This is Clickable
    //echo $customer['CardName'];
}
?>

        </td>
        <td><?php echo $customer['CardType'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $customer['Name'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $customer['ZipCode'] ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

As to making it clickable, we would need to know more about the url you want to go to and the parameters you want to send to it in an anchor tag, but for example

This line

```
<?php echo $customer['CardName']; ?>
```

Could be something like

```
<?php echo "<a href='folder/file.php?param=something'>{$customer['CardName']} </a>" ?>
```